# Compare averaged GLM with boosted regression trees using cross validation : d2 and RMSE calculation

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, cross-validation

I want to compare BRT and averaged glm models on test sets by calculating the explained deviance and RMSE. 
How can I calculate d2 and RMSE from predictions?
I use the following functions:

> gbm1 <- gbm.step(data=ahe2,
>                  gbm.x = c(2,4:5,7:9,11),#15
>                   gbm.y = 10,
>                   family = "poisson",
>                   tree.complexity = k,
>                   nfolds=10,
>                   bag.fraction = 0.50,
>                   n.trees=nb,
>                   learning.rate=z,
>                   tolerance.method = "fixed",
>                   tolerance = 0.01)

## GLM poisson

> glm1=glm(larve~chla+station+
>             vit+direct+lune+
>             temp,data=ahe2,family="poisson")
>
> dd=dredge(glm1,rank="QAICc",chat=c_hat(glm1))
>
> models.list <- get.models(dd,subset = cumsum(weight) <= .95)
>
> muminavg.quasi <- model.avg(models.list)

## I split data:

> kfold1=createFolds(ahe2$larve, k = 10, list = T)

After that, I will use predict() on the prediction set.

I thought to calculate RMSE with the square root of the mean squared residuals.  For deviance, and particularly for gbm1, I don’t know how to proceed (t(residuals(glm1))%*%residuals(glm1) ?).

I also wanted to implement a averaged gam but don’t know to plot it.